# Wait 10 seconds after send command in RabbitListener

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, axon

I have my RabbitListener witch received results of calculations. This is the lot of data so i batched it and next send a command to axon commandGateway. I wonder if it is possible for the listener to wait a few seconds before sending next command. I note that i can't use threadSleep here. It could be work something like this method for every batch

```
private void myMethod() {
  commandGateway.send(batchedData) 
   //wait 10seconds
```

Comment: Why can't you use `Thread.sleep()`? Even if the container supported such a concept, it would probably do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reason for having a waiting period here?

If the reason is to wait before Axon Framework has processed all data present in the command, you can use `commandGateway.sendAndWait(Object command, ...)` instead. This will make the current thread wait for the command to have been executed.

If it is a mechanism to batch the data, I would suggest keeping an in-memory `List` to queue the items, and then sending a command every 10 seconds using the Spring scheduling mechanism. I created a small example in Kotlin to illustrate this:

```kotlin
@Service
class CalculationBatcher(
    private val commandGateway: CommandGateway
) {
    private val calculationQueue = LinkedList<Any>()

    fun queueCalculation(calculation: Any) {
        calculationQueue.add(calculation)
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000) // Send every 10 seconds
    @PreDestroy // When destroying the application, send remaining events
    fun sendCalculations() {
        // Use pop here on the LinkedList while having items to prevent threading issues
        val calculationsToSend = LinkedList<Any>()
        while (calculationQueue.isNotEmpty()) {
            calculationsToSend.push(calculationQueue.pop())
        }
        commandGateway.sendAndWait<Any>(MyEventsCommand(calculationsToSend), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }

    data class MyEventsCommand(val events: List<Any>)
}
```

I hope this helps. If the reason was something else, let me know!